# Past Simple or Past Perfect in the context of something having been done by the exact time yesterday

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

Here goes a sentence:

> Alice said that she had translated three articles by five o’clock
>   yesterday.

My question is as follows:

If what Alice exactly said was *"I had translated three articles by five o’clock yesterday"*, would that be a grammatically correct sentence? Or should there the Simple Past tense be used, when telling about what happened yesterday *by the exact time*? My gut feeling tells me, it should (or might), but I can't find the reference hard as I try. Could anyone help?

P.S. I wouldn't have thought of asking it hadn't I come across the test where the sentence *"I had translated three articles by five o’clock yesterday"* was marked as the only correct answer.

Comment: No,it's p-e-r-f-e-c-t. The translating there precedes the saying.

Comment: @Lambie Were it "by the time the film started", yes, and there'd be no question about it, but having nothing to move further into the past from...

Comment: @Lambie I'm afraid you don't get my drift--anything that happened in the past precedes telling about it.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97551/which-is-the-correct-tense-to-use-with-by

Comment: @userr2684291 Thanks for the link, but the question there even if it might seem to be related to mine, then somewhat rather distantly, at least for my money. Besides, I don't find those explanations to be of much help without any links to reliable sources--just personal opinions.

Comment: If Alice said *I had translated three articles by five o'clock yesterday*, the reported sentence is *Alice said she had translated three articles by five o'clock yesterday/the day before*. Now, whether the past simple is equally idiomatic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is usually a reason for using the PP.

Context: What did she say **she did** yesterday by 5 o'clock?
- Alice said she translated three articles by 5 o'clock yesterday.
- **That means at 5 o'clock yesterday, the work was done.**
The simple past signals a finished state or condition or activity in the past. There is no specificity to "pastness" of the utterance.

Context: What did she say she **had done** by 5 o'clock yesterday?
- Alice said she **had translated** three articles by 5 o'clock today.
- **That means at 5 o'clock, the work **had been** done.
The past perfect emphasizes the fact the translations came before that time. The simple past does not.

The point on the timeline, five o'clock, could be something like:

Alice said she **had translated** three articles by 5 o'clock** but the fourth one she only  translated after that.

The past perfect is used to emphasize something. **The past perfect is always used contrastively with another tense either explicitly or by an implied contextual verb.**. One never uses it ex-nihilo. :)

So, in the OP's sample sentence, its use would be predicated by surrounding context that is not given.

Comment: And would I be right saying that in the past tense "by 7 o'clock" will always imply "before clocks stroke seven"?

Comment: Well, it would be up to and including it.

Comment: @Lambie Then what is the difference between:

"She translated it by 5 o'clock = it was translated at 5 o'clock" and "She translated it at 5 o'clock = it was translated at 5 o'clock"?

Comment: @Lambie You need a separate question from me?